# Upper bound of the largest eigenvalue of $DAAD$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

$H = DAAD$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix and the elements on the diagonal are real numbers (could be positive and negative). $A$ is positive semi-definite and can be diagonalized into $A=U^T\Lambda U$. Then we can convert $H=DU^T\Lambda^2UD$. I am wondering how to estimate the upper bound of the largest eigenvalue of $H$. Please help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: How good an estimate do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The magic words are "Ostrowski's Theorem":

*Ostrowski, A. M.*, [**A quantitative formulation of Sylvester’s law of inertia**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.45.5.740), Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 45, 740-744 (1959). [ZBL0087.01802](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0087.01802).